# How do i save different kinds of input?

Tags: c, input, struct

i was trying to write a c program where the input consists of zero, one or two positive integers (if two then they are separated by a comma) and a character. The problem is that i need do save the input but i really don't know how since i can't be sure about how many numbers there will be before the character. At first i was thinking about using a structure but it doesn't work unless there are two numbers. To give you an example, all these inputs would be correct:

```
2,5 c
3,9 d
4 u
2 r
q
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Save *where*? In variables in memory? What have you tried? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a couple of hints: Pleas read about the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) functions. Pay close attention to what `sscanf`[*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: @Andrea - Can the _character_ be a digit?

Comment: no, it has to be a character

Comment: so before creating  the structure i should save the input in an array and count how many integers are used?

Comment: Thank you!!! i think this could work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In MPI for multiple process scanf taking input only once and assign garbage values to other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802334/in-mpi-for-multiple-process-scanf-taking-input-only-once-and-assign-garbage-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example in a file, read each line with `fgets`.
Use `sscanf` to parse each line.
A different `sscanf` for each combination of values. If the first `sscanf` fails to scan four values, the second `sscanf` tries to scan three values and finally try to scan one value.
This uses only one instance of the structure. An array of structures could be used or a linked list of structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Item {
    int one;
    int two;
    char letter;
    char used;
} item;

int main ( void) {
    //int scanned = 0;
    char line[100] = "";
    item values = { 0, 0, 0, 0};
    FILE *fin = NULL;

    if ( NULL == ( fin = fopen ( "file.txt", "r"))) {
        perror ( "file.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fin)) {
        if ( 4 == sscanf ( line, "%d%c%d %c", &values.one, &values.used, &values.two, &values.letter)) {
            printf ( "one %d   used [%c]   two %d   letter %c\n"
            , values.one, values.used, values.two, values.letter);
        }
        else if ( 3 == sscanf ( line, "%d%c %c", &values.one, &values.used, &values.letter)) {
            values.two = 0;
            printf ( "one %d   used [%c]   letter %c\n"
            , values.one, values.used, values.letter);
        }
        else if ( 1 == sscanf ( line, " %c", &values.letter)) {
            values.one = 0;
            values.two = 0;
            values.used = 0;
            printf ( "letter %c\n", values.letter);
        }
    }

    fclose ( fin);

    return 0;
}
```

File

```
2,5 c
3,9 d
4 u
2 r
q
```

Output

```
one 2   used [,]   two 5   letter c
one 3   used [,]   two 9   letter d
one 4   used [ ]   letter u
one 2   used [ ]   letter r
letter q
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, where you want to save your data. But in you have many data structure for save your input.

You can create a Structure array example:

```
typedef struct data_set_s {

 char *name;
 int age;
 char *city
} data_set_t;
```

If you don't know the size of your dataSet you can use an linked list.

You have a good exemple and explication to how create and understand an linked list: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

If you want to you can save your input in .txt.

I don't know if I answered your question correctly

Comment: I think that in this case a struct doesn't work since i don't know how many numbers the input has, so i am trying to save all the input into a string and then count how many numbers were used. Anyway thanks for the answer